# My app is running fine on ics but not in froyo

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-compatibility

**I have this app where in I have the below shown layout as the starting activity.It works fine in ICS but not in froyo.**

[image]

**In froyo it only shows the ABOUT button and nothing else. I have also updated my manifest file below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.iolcalci"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:resizeable="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iolcalci.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iolcalci.Selection"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan|stateVisible" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iolcalci.Srkt"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_srkt"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iolcalci.Srk2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_srk2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iolcalci.Holladay"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_holladay"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iolcalci.Binkhorst"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_binkhorst"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iolcalci.Srkt_x"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_srkt_x" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iolcalci.Srk2_x"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_srk2_x" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iolcalci.Binkhorst_x"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_binkhorst_x" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iolcalci.Holladay_x"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_holladay_x" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.iolcalci.Help"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

**XML file is here**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" 
android:id="@+id/frame_layout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="@style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
        android:layout_width="222dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/iolCalculation"
        android:text="@string/Button"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
        android:layout_width="222dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/sHelp"
        android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Button1"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
        android:layout_width="222dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:id="@+id/sAbout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="203dp"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/Button2"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textStyle="bold" >

    </Button>
```

---

**froyo screen**

[image]

---

**Please help me and is there any way to test my app for froyo on pc?**

Comment: Paste your xml file. We need to see the layout file.

Comment: Are the resolutions of the Froyo and ICS devices the same?

Comment: @Torcellite you mean the screen size?

Comment: @Torcellite ya the app is working fine in 3.2 inch ics whereas in 3.2 inch froyo oly the about button appears at the top of screen. cheeck my updated question

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi You've closed the Linear layout without anything in it. What is it for? I think that's probably the problem.

Comment: @Torcellite ok will check it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23442/discussion-between-ahambrahmaasmi-and-torcellite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" 
android:id="@+id/frame_layout">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/iolCalculation"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sHelp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sAbout"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >

</Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This code works on all OSes. Do refrain from using fixed widths and heights!